# Geodesic normal coordinates in constant curvature space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^{n},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with constant sectional $K$. Assume that in the geodesic normal coordinate $ (r,\theta^{1},\cdots, \theta^{n-1}) $, the metric $g$ has the form $g=dr^2+(f(r))^2h_{ij}(\theta)d\theta^{i}d\theta^{j}$, where the (n-1)-dimensional metric $h_{ij}(\theta)d\theta^{i}d\theta^{j}$ has constant sectional curvature 1.

I want to ask how to prove that
\begin{align*}
  f(r)=\begin{cases}
   \sin(\sqrt{Kr^2})/\sqrt{K},\quad &K>0;\\\ r,\quad &K=0;\\\ \sinh(\sqrt{-Kr^2})/\sqrt{-K},\quad &K<0.
    \end{cases}
 \end{align*}

Comment: Confirm that these coordinates satisfy the definition of geodesic normal coordinates. Which definition do you know?

Comment: If you have the metric $ds^2=dr^2+f(r)^2\,d\theta^2$ on $\Bbb R^2$, calculate the curvature. You will get a simple ODE to solve for $f(r)$ if you want to set $K=K_0$.